# Dynamic method invocation based on URL Param

Tags: url, struts2, struts, dmi

I want to hit a URL such as `/mysite/test?do_this?execution_method`

I want this to take me to the action method `execution_method()`

via the following `struts.xml` action

```xml
<action
    name="/mysite/test"
    class="com.app.test"
    method="{do_this}">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I know the above doesn't work, but how do we get the URL query param to be executed?

Comment: Same way DMI does it now, I guess (reflection); there's no two-level DMI functionality built in to S2. Nor would I think it's a terribly good idea--DMI is edge-case as it is. Can you describe *why* you want to do this in case there's a reasonable alternative?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to kick DMI out from the user perspective. DMI is strictly internal and havilly use reflection mechanism to be very slow at Performance. Why did you try to retrieve a method using expression?